# How to retrieve SCTs when using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl, certificate-transparency

I am not getting any SCTs when using OpenSSL. After setting up the SSL connection, I'm calling

```
SSL_enable_ct(ssl, SSL_CT_VALIDATION_PERMISSIVE);
const STACK_OF(SCT) *sct_stack = sk_SCT_new_null();
sct_stack = SSL_get0_peer_scts(ssl);
printf("%i SCTs obtained.\n", sk_SCT_num(sct_stack));
```

And it always prints out that I obtained 0 SCTs, regardless of the domain that I connect to. The thing is, the connection is being setup correctly, because I can grab the X509 certificate for any domain I connect to, and I can send OCSP requests and obtain responses to those requests. But when I try to grab the SCTs that should be sent, my code always informs me that there were no SCTs.

I have a strong feeling that it is my code that isn't working, because even when I connect to one of google's websites, such as google.com or gmail.com, I am unable to obtain any SCTs from the connection, despite the fact that Google pioneered certificate transparency.

Comment: I think `SSL_enable_ct()` must be called *before* a connection is made

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how SSL connections work, but I will try calling it before the connection is made

Comment: `grep -IR SSL_get0_peer_scts` in the OpenSSL sources shows several hits including `apps/s_client.c:  const STACK_OF(SCT) *scts = SSL_get0_peer_scts(s);`. Maybe you can verify the same behavior from `s_client`, and then look at the `s_client` code at [`<openssl src>/apps/s_client.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/s_client.c). The call to `SSL_ct_is_enabled(ssl)` looks kind of interesting to me. The comments about the anonymous session also look interesting.